# trying to do an atomic update to a file on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to make an atomic update to a file on google drive .. i.e. the update should only succeed if the file hasn't changed since I last downloaded it.

I am using the If-Match:  header in the update request

The problem I am running into is that I download the file using the following endpoint:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/${fileId}?alt=media`

The response contains the content of the file in the body and returns an etag in a response header like so:

`etag:""hcahzZRGAO5dFBAGGfvDlnfbXEY/LTExOTA5OTEyOTk""`

However, this etag DOES NOT equal the etag I get if I simply queried for the file metadata .. using

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/${fileId}`

Not surprisingly, If I try to do an update of the file using `If-Match: <etag>` received during the download, the update fails with a error 'pre-condition failed'

It is obviously not an ideal situation to do an http request to get the etag from a file meta data and then use that etag to do an update, because some other process might have changed the file in the meanwhile.

How can I get the etag for a file along with the download of the file itself?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any way to be sure that you have the correct etag of a file! Yeah, you can do a get for the metadata, and then use the `downloadurl` to actually fetch the file, but how do you know the file hasn't changed between the two requests. Shouldn't a file download return an `etag` that matches the file's actual `etag`?